# Can team members vote for my posts?

Tags: discussion, voting, serial-voting, sock-puppets

The situation is as follows: there are 6 people in the team, we work together and come up to an answer/question. They all have legit profiles - they are not sock puppets. However, sometimes we do upvote a post if we consider that it might help us individually or as a team.

**Question:** might this be considered a voting anomaly?

There is a small paragraph in [meta blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/more-voting-anomalies/):

> We now perform a more detailed statistical analysis on voting patterns. Any voting patterns that are too far outside the statistical norm will be nullified.

Does it applies to my situation?

Comment: This could easily be considered a voting ring.

Comment: Voting should be on posts, not the people who posted them. If people in your team vote for your posts, they are voting because of the person, not the post.